# New to Matlab - Not sure how to run these files

Tags: matlab, driver

The files I would like to run are found here:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12552-multicanonical-monte-carlo-scheme-for-finding-rare-growth-factors/content/mcmc2.m

it consists of 3 files, one of which is called a driver.

I have tried running each individual one in Matlab and each one gets an error, I think this is because I need to run them all simultaneously or something?

At the beginning of the driver script it says "This is the driver script to be run from the command line. Also requires functions mcmc1 and mcmc2". Where mcmc1 and mcmc2 are the other two files I tried running it in command line but I kept getting error messages..

Any idea how I get these files to run?

Comment: What errors?  Do you have the Distributed Computing Toolbox that the script comments mentions is used?

Comment: Save all the files in the same folder. Navigate to that folder. Then, type of the name of the driver file in the command line. If an error occurs let us know what the error is.

Comment: The file opens in matlab in the background and I get a long list of errors pop up:

Comment: Java.lang.illegalstateexception: user home directory is not a valid directory    Is the first error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to run `gf_mmc_driver` from the command line in Matlab. The `mcmc1.m` and `mcmc2.m` files need to be in your matlab path, but do not need to be called directly.

However, I do notice in the driver file the following comment:

```
% Telling the Distributed Computing Toolbox to complete one job with 
% 'numberchain' tasks.  Each task is comprised of running a MCMC 
% for the burnin time (mcmc1.m) with a different initial matrix.
```

Do you have the Distributed Computing Toolbox? The driver file appears to require it.

Comment: How would I go about checking if I have the Distributed Computing Toolbox?

Comment: Just noticed that I don't have it installed. Installing it now. Thanks